# How can i write nested query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following FROM follows WHERE user_id='1'
```

This is the query i want to wirte in laravel to fetch the data how can i write this in laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result = DB::table('posts')
    ->whereIn('user_id', function ($query) {
        $query->select('following')
            ->from('follows')
            ->where('user_id', 1);
    })->get();
```

Comment: yes it works Thanks You, i'm new to laravel and searching for hours about this

Comment: @Yash You should peruse https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database and https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships, then.